# IE7/IE8 are not handling my stress test of Raphael well, any ideas on how to improve performance?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, raphael, stress-testing

I have created a basic stress test of Raphaёl (the well-known vector library) that displays 1000 objects (with connections) on screen.

In Firefox, this works splendidly. It displays all 1000 objects, and I can move them around at will with no visible lag (lag only ensues when I get to around 20,000 objects).

This is all on a mid-grade corporate desktop, keep in mind.

When I attempt to run my demo on IE7, it goes unbearably slow. And it doesn't run at all on IE8. It really only works reasonably well when I have around 50 objects on screen in IE7/IE8.

I am creating a test suite that will at minimum require 200 test steps to be drawn at a time, and I really must figure out a way optimize my JavaScript code for IE7/IE8. Any ideas?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TTR35/. You're welcome.

Comment: That is an amazing site!  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to load in IE8....which is the only version of IE I have installed atm.

Comment: I know you said not to complain about IE too much, but I should tell you that Microsoft actually managed to make VML graphics slower in IE7 and even worse in IE8 compared with IE6. As much as I love Raphael, I'd say that you just need to take it easy with the graphic effects if you want it to work in IE. (and no, I'm *not* suggesting you switch back to IE6 to get the graphics working faster!!!! ;-))

Comment: I read somewhere that there are some issues in the Raphael-layer between VML and IE, and that VML in IE is actually reasonably fast.  Is this true?